# ListView Items are showing across the whole screen

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I'm trying to make my first application on Android Studio (To-Do app), but I got stuck. The problems I'm facing:

1. "ListView Items are showing across the screen, when I write into the EditText field".
   [image]
   [image]
2. "After I'm done writing my goal, I can't press "BUILD!" button right away, I've to do 'back' button once, to make "BUILD!" button react."

[image]

What's the right approach here? Any suggestion on code will be highly appreciated!

JAVA:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList<String> items;
private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
private ListView lvItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
}

// ADDING YOUR FUTURE GOALS!
public void onBuildButton(View v){

    EditText dreamText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dreamText);
    String itemText = dreamText.getText().toString();
    itemsAdapter.add(itemText);
    dreamText.setText("");
}
}
```

XML:

```
... 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context="com.example.mrti.todo.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#F55449"
    android:id="@+id/belowTask"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dreamText"
        android:hint="@string/build_your_dreams"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#c5c5c5"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/UnderLine"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dreamText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#FFCD2626"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="@string/build"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFCD2626"
        android:id="@+id/buildButton"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:onClick="onBuildButton" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
```

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you

Comment: If you find that any of the answers has worked for you, mark it as the correct/accepted answer so that others may find it helpful in the future. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are mentioning this is your first android app so would advice you to stay away from any deprecated methods, properties or anything like "fill_parent"

You can keep the ListView below the insert box by

```
android:layout_below="@id/belowTask"
```

Note: this "layout_below" is a parameter of a RelativeLayout

As a result the top box will always stay there and incase the keyboard showed up then the size of the ListView will shrink (because the bottom is now the keyboard top)

Here is how your layout would look like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context="com.example.mrti.todo.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/belowTask"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#F55449"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dreamText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/build_your_dreams"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="60dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#c5c5c5" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/UnderLine"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="#FFCD2626"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buildButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            android:background="#FFCD2626"
            android:onClick="onBuildButton"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:text="@string/build" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/belowTask" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Android Development.

A small note before starting :

> full_parent is deprecated. Use match_parent instead

Additionally, it is not visible whether you are using a RelativeLayout or a LinearLayout on the top-most xml element, but I will be assuming a RelativeLayout given the alignParentStart on the subsequent views.

**The problem is within the 'alignParentTop' & 'alignParentBottom' on the layouts. Since you're using a RelativeLayout, views can be aligning between each other.**

You have also defined a specific size for the ListView. 
You can do it in 2 ways :

**1 - limit this size of the ListView by doing**. This means you will have a solid ListView with a limited size, regardless of newly added entries.

```
android:layout_height="320dp"
```

**2 - Letting it adjust to the values you insert by doing**. This means your ListView will grow in size as you add more entries

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Either way, that should suffice. This is the full xml.
Let me know of your results.

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.mrti.todo.MainActivity"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#F55449"
            android:id="@+id/belowTask"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/listView"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="@string/build_your_dreams"
                android:id="@+id/dreamText"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="60dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#c5c5c5" />

            <View
                android:background="#FFCD2626"
                android:id="@+id/UnderLine"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dreamText"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp" />

            <Button
                android:background="#FFCD2626"
                android:id="@+id/buildButton"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onBuildButton"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:text="@string/build" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```